# How to merge two functions in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am successfully opening a JQuery dialog modal. My first JQuery function opens dialog and my second jquery function set the dialog position to top. I want to merge these two functions, please see my following code:-

```
$(function () {
    $("#modal-registration").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 380,
        model: true
    });
    $('#modal-registration').dialog({ position: 'top' });
});
```

In above code how can i merge these  two functions like  `$("#modal-registration").dialog({autoOpen:false, et:cetera})`  and the `$('#modal-registration').dialog({ position: 'top' });` with each other?, thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8so7bug8/  $('#dialog').dialog( 'option', 'position', [0, 0] ); change 0,0 to x,y coordinates of your need

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just stick the position property in with the first dialog call? Like

```
$("#modal-registration").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 400,
  width: 380,
  model: true,
  position: 'top'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#modal-registration").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 400,
                width: 380,
                model: true,
                position: 'top' 

            })
```

Why not in single command?

Comment: Please see my code, in which i have two functions, now how can i merge them? thanks $(document).ready(function () { $("#modal-registration").dialog({ show: "slide", modal: true, autoOpen: false, height: 400, width: 380, position: 'top', overflow:'hidden' }); $('#modal-registration').css('overflow', 'hidden');

Comment: $("#modal-registration").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                height: 400,
                width: 380,
                model: true,
                position: 'top' 
            }).css('overflow', 'hidden')

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8so7bug8/)

### HTML

```
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
```

### Jquery

```
$('#dialog').dialog( 'option', 'position', [0, 0] );
```

change [0,0] to x,y coordinates of your need

Answer (score 0):

As per your fiddle link, you can do following :

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({    
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 380,
    model: true,
    position : [0,0]        //mention the attribute here itself
});
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Its working fine.

Comment: Please see my code, in which i have two functions, now how can i merge them? thanks  $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#modal-registration").dialog({
                    show: "slide",
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 400,
                    width: 380,
                    position: 'top',
                    overflow:'hidden'
                });
                $('#modal-registration').css('overflow', 'hidden');